# Как удалить атрибут элемента при помощи JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как убрать все атрибуты тега  `style`

```
<style scope="scope">
```

То бишь  scope="scope"

Comment: На сколько помнится у данного тега есть только 2 аттрибута: `media` и `type` - которые не обязательные, аттрибут `scope` отсутствует. Это только `mozilla` - поддерживает.

Comment: Да вот мне или убрать, вообще скриптом или заменить на type="text/css"

Comment: Просто написать `<style>` и ничего убирать не надо будет? Или это откуда-то прилетает? Только вот не понятно, почему клиентом решаете, а не на сервере?

Comment: просто написать да <style>, а убрать scope="scope". Делаю клиентом, так как не могу найти плагин который вообще это вставляет

Comment: Но ведь клиент не умеет менять на сервере, по этому у вас всегда будет то, что на сервере, а не то, что сделал клиент без участия сервера.

Comment: `так как не могу найти плагин который вообще это вставляет` - что мешает воспользоваться поиском текста по файлам? И найти файл в котором это вставлено и убрать.

Comment: Не находит к сожалению(

Comment: похоже на vue, и этот атрибут автоматически убирается при сборке с vue

Comment: вот как его найти, куча плагинов установлена на wordpresse

Comment: Если wordpress - то скорее всего никак, так как это немного другая технология. В любом случае, если бы использовался vue - он бы сам убирал эти атрибуты. Где ты увидел эти атрибуты, и почему решил, что их надо убрать?

Comment: https://mirinoi.by/ вот здесь, атрибут у style, ооткуда вообще он не понятно

Answer (score 2):

С помощью [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

```js
styleTag.removeAttribute('scope');

console.log(styleTag.outerHTML);
```

```html
<style id="styleTag" scope="scope"></style>
```

Comment: А если нет id? просто на всей странице

Comment: @razmenyairu `document.querySelectorAll('style')`

Comment: просто находит все стили, а мне нужно просто удалить на всей странице  scope="scope", чтоб стало <style>

Comment: @razmenyairu боюсь с таким подходом вам не сюда, а на fl.ru

Answer (score 2):

`scope="scope"` — аттрибут элемента. Чтобы удалить все аттрибуты, не нужен jQuery:

```
while (elem.attributes.length > 0)
    elem.removeAttribute(elem.attributes[0].name);
```

Чтобы проитерироваться по всем элементам документа:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     // ваши действия
}
```

Или с jQuery:

```
$(document.documentElement).children().each(function(index, element) {
    // ваши действия
});
```

Всё вместе:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    var elem = all[i];
    while (elem.attributes.length > 0)
        elem.removeAttribute("scope");
}
```

---

Как отмечено в комментариях, можно и сразу выбрать только нужные элементы (только те, что содержат нужный аттрибут)

jQuery:

```
$("[scope]").each(function(index, element) {
    element.removeAttribute("scope");
});
```

Comment: Атрибут? которого нет в спецификациях... Как на всей странице удалить?

Comment: @razmenyairu не думаю, что есть разница, присутствует ли аттрибут в спецификациях. Насчёт всей страницы, дополнил ответ.

Comment: А что должно быть в ваши действия? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @razmenyairu вам что необходимо сделать? Удалить аттрибуты. Значит вам нужно проитерироваться по всем элементам, и у каждого удалить аттрибуты. Как сделать первое и второе, я показал в ответе. Вам нужно лишь совместить.

Comment: Вот я сделал, но выдает ошибку VM3686:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: elem is not defined

Comment: @razmenyairu дополнил ответ. Последний пример используйте.

Comment: удалились все атрибуты во всех style, вот гляньте https://mirinoi.by/

Comment: @razmenyairu я думал, вы хотя бы на это обратите внимание. Ещё раз дополнил ответ.

Comment: Не знаю как проверить) вставил в консоль, нажал enter и все вкладка с сайтом повисла(

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, не обязательно выбирать все элементы, достаточно выбрать те. у которых этот атрибут есть.